# the implementation of FileIO::Read()

Tags: google-nativeclient

when i read the source code of fileIO::read().I came across a problem.
First of all,the fileIO::Read() source code is:

```
enter int32_t FileIO::Read(int64_t offset,
                 char* buffer,
                 int32_t bytes_to_read,
                 const CompletionCallback& cc)
  {
    if (has_interface<PPB_FileIO_1_1>()) {
      return get_interface<PPB_FileIO_1_1>()->Read(pp_resource(),
          offset, buffer, bytes_to_read, cc.pp_completion_callback());
   } else if (has_interface<PPB_FileIO_1_0>()) {
      return get_interface<PPB_FileIO_1_0>()->Read(pp_resource(),
    offset, buffer, bytes_to_read, cc.pp_completion_callback());
  }
  return cc.MayForce(PP_ERROR_NOINTERFACE);
}
```

we can see that across get_interface(),we get a Func Pointer.the problem is, how to get this pointer.
then i find the source code of get_interface:

```
template <typename T> inline T const* get_interface() {
  static T const* funcs = reinterpret_cast<T const*>(
  pp::Module::Get()->GetBrowserInterface(interface_name<T>()));
  return funcs;
}
```

and then the source code of GetBrowserInterface(),

```
const void* Module::GetBrowserInterface(const char* interface_name) {
  return get_browser_interface_(interface_name);
}

Module::Module() : pp_module_(0), get_browser_interface_(NULL), core_(NULL){}
```

we can see that when construct the Module,we set the get_browser_interface_ to NULL,and i find nowhere that InternalInit() Func wasn't called at all.
so it Confuses that how to get the Read() Pointer.And where are the source code of the implemention of Read()? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pp::Module::InternalInit` is called in `ppp_entrypoints.cc`. The functions in this file are called as the entrypoint to the PPAPI Native Client module when you link in the ppapi_cpp library.

Specifically, `PPP_InitializeModule` is called by the module loader to initialize the Native Client module.

The source code of `PPB_FileIO_1_1::Read` can be found in the ppapi library [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/ppapi/thunk/ppb_file_io_thunk.cc&l=68). This forwards to the proxy [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/ppapi/proxy/file_io_resource.cc&l=238).

Comment: thank you very much!
Besides that,i have another question.
I use VS2012 to compile the source.and generate the libs.But there is a mismatch between the symbols that libs and VS2012 compile result.For example, a function pp::Instance::Init(uint32_t, const char*, const char*,).I use this function in my projiect.And i use the libs the I generated by VS2012.But the compiler says can not find the symbol ??pp::Instance::Init2h3j2(Of course the name is mangled, i can't remember the exact name).And i use dumpbin to export the symbols of libs.I find out the symbols(after mangled) are different.

Comment: It confuses me, i use VS2012 to generate the libs and i use VS2012 to compile my projiect, why the same symbol are different after mangled?It should be the same mangling mechanism?Is the MAKEFILE worng?

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the command line arguments used when compiling both the libraries and the executable. Perhaps you'll be able to find the discrepancy that causes the names to be mangled differently.